# Nginx Load Balancer Strategy - Traffic Always to the same server

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have 2 different upstreams for different continents (America & Europe)

I want each to send traffic always to the same server, however I need to specify 2 servers on each in case of a downtime - Traffic should be sent to the alternative server.

The problem is that there is no strategy to perform this. I did the workaround of weight=1000000000 on the preferred server, but I feel this is not the correct way.

```
upstream US_UPSTREAM  {
    ip_hash;
    server 2.2.2.2 weight=100000000 max_fails=10  fail_timeout=3600s;
    server 1.1.1.1 #should only be used as backup, not round robin or any other strategy
}

upstream EU_UPSTREAM {
    ip_hash;
    server 1.1.1.1 weight=100000000 max_fails=10  fail_timeout=3600s;
    server 2.2.2.2 #should only be used as backup, not round robin or any other strategy
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `backup` option?

Comment: Yes, this was the way! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally discovered how to fix this.

The backup alone did not work. If the first server was offline I would get a 502 from it. The key to put it working was to add the backup on the second server, and also set the error on location:

```
location / {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
      proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;


      proxy_pass http://$preferred_upstream$request_uri;
      *proxy_next_upstream error http_502;*
}
```

upstream

```
upstream eu_upstream {
    ip_hash;
    server 1.1.1.1 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=3600s;
    server 2.2.2.2 *backup*;
}
```